# Open fancybox iframe with delay

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use fancybox for showing iframe, but I want animation on link, so I need to delay fancybox popup.
I've tried some solutions from here, but nothing worked for me.
Here is my code, thank you for help!

JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.stesti').click(function () {
       setTimeout(function(){      
           $('.stesti').addClass('fancybox');
          $(".stesti").trigger('click');
       }, 3000);
});
     </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button"><a class="stesti fancybox.iframe button" href="iframe.html"></a></div>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you not seeing the animation? Is something not happening with the iFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to open Fancybox manually:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.stesti').click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents browser following the link
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // save the url

    setTimeout(function(){
      // Open Fancybox manually:
      $.fancybox.open([{
        type : 'iframe',
        href: href
      }]);
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include jquery and fancybox files -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<!-- Your link: -->
<a class="stesti button" href="/iframe.html">Link</a>
```